# Angular bind ViewChild to Property in Class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tree, expression

I'm trying to figure out how to bind a view child to a child component of a class inside of my view.

I have a models that emulates binary expression:

```
export interface IODataExpression{

}

export class ODataExpressionDescriptor implements IODataExpression{
    property: ODataProperty;
    selectedFunction: ODataFunctionDescriptor;
    value: any;
    isNegated: boolean = false;
}

export class ODataBinaryExpressionDescriptor implements IODataExpression{
    left: IODataExpression;
    right: IODataExpression;
    operator: ODataBinaryOperators;
}
```

I have a component class which looks like so:

```
 binaryExpression: ODataBinaryExpressionDescriptor = new ODataBinaryExpressionDescriptor();
 binaryOperatorKeys: any;

 binaryOperators = ODataBinaryOperators;

 @ViewChild('left') leftExpression: OdataSimpleFilterComponent;
```

the left property points to a component which internally has a property:

```
odataExpression: ODataExpressionDescriptor = new ODataExpressionDescriptor();
```

How can I make it so that the `binaryExpression.left` always equals the view childs `leftExpression.odataExpression`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `EventEmitter`.

In `OdataSimpleFilterComponent`

```
@Output() odataExpressionChange = new EventEmitter<ODataExpressionDescriptor>();
```

Then, whenever tha value changes internally in the component, you do:

```
this.odataExpressionChange.emit(this.odataExpression);
```

In the main component, you'll have to do in `ngAfterViewInit` (or `ngAfterViewChecked`), to make sure that `leftExpression` is initialised:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    leftExpression.odataExpressionChange.subscribe(data => {
        this.binaryExpression.left = data;
    }
}
```

This way, whenever the value changes in the child component, you'll receive a notification (via the subsrcription to the `EventEmitter`) and can react accordingly.

Of course some details might change, as I can't know all of the details of your implementation.

Comment: Perfect, give me a second to try this out

Comment: Sorry that tooks so long